# Short and Sweet (Riley riddle)

Tags: wordplay

Entry into Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

Riddle me this:

> My prefix is able in aluminum,
>
> My suffix asks for the reason.
>
> My infix it neither or nor xand,
>
> And I should please you all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is-

> Candy (it pleases everyone)

Prefix-

> Can (able, aluminum can)

Infix-

> And (not Or, not Xand)

Suffix-

> Y  (Why)

Comment: Well done! @Shahriar

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I had an alternative solution. Then I noticed that it is slightly misspelled. But I still feel it is close enough that it can be posted.

Prefix

> "lu" is what comes after "a" in aluminum

Infix

> xor is another logical operator

Suffix

> "y" as "why"

When said aloud, the combination sounds like

> luxury

which is pleasing to those who have it.

Comment: Nice Try... +1 for consolation!